# Horizontal scrollbar issue

Tags: jquery, html, css, xhtml

I have an issue with a div containing lots of "tiles" in fixed width height divs, I want it to scroll horizontally, so the tiles inside the container scroll with the scrollbar.

Here's some stuff in jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/jNbxU/2/

It's got stuff missing, but the essentials are there. If you click a box, "For Kids" for example, then view the container labelled "now choose a picture" the divs within that "design 1, design 2, etc" shouldn't wrap to two rows, they should all be on one row and scroll. I can't get it to work...

Any help would be awesome, thanks. :D

Answer (score 0):

What you need for that effect, is a container in a container. The outer container has an `overflow: scroll` and fixed dimensions to allow for scrolling and the inner container has a very large width that is big enough to accommodate all elements in it. I normally use javascript to set the width of the inner container to exactly the width of all elements (+ margins / borders).

In html it would look something like:

```
<div class="outer">
  <ul class="inner">
    <li></li> 
    <li></li> 
    <li></li> 
    <li></li> 
    <li></li> 
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

There are also solutions that use things like `white-space: nowrap` on the inner container, but the last time I tried that I could not get it to work reliably across browsers.